# open CV (python) my code has a problem with imread. It is not working as expected all the outputs are zero

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, imread

I am using python to learn open CV and while I was trying to image process I came up with a problem. My code is like this:

```
import numpy as np   
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("Pictures/sun.jpg")`
img
```

When I print img normally I should be able to see various numbers indicating their color. But my output is like this: ...

```
[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]
```

I checked if I wrote the correct path and also did this process with different pictures to try to understand if it is because of the image but its not. So how can I fix this problem?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: do there happen to be black pixels

Comment: What does `np.unique(img)` show you?  Does it only contain 0?